# modifying a group of WinForm controls using a loop?

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, loops, textbox

I have a group of textbox controls that i would like to populate with an array of doubles.The controls names are numerically incremented like so

```
Tol1.Text = lineTolFront[0].ToString();
Tol2.Text = lineTolFront[1].ToString();
Tol3.Text = lineTolFront[2].ToString();
Tol4.Text = lineTolFront[3].ToString();
Tol5.Text = lineTolFront[4].ToString();
Tol6.Text = lineTolFront[5].ToString(); 
//and so on
```

is there a simpler way to do this using a loop without having to manually input the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get all those TextBoxes using LINQ (note: this is useful particularly when you have many controls you do not want manually put in a collection).

```
var tboxes = this.Controls.Cast<Control>()
                 .OfType<TextBox>()
                 .Where(l => l.Name.Contains("Tol"));
```

and then loop through them and set the content.

```
int i = 0;
foreach(var tb in tboxes)
    tb.Text = lineTolFront[i++].ToString();
```

Comment: @GrantWinney Thank you. I'm trying to solve the problem at hand, not every possible problem that might arise from this one ;)

Comment: @GrantWinney Yeah, you can always add ordering to the query if it's actually needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could add the TextBoxes to a collection first. It's a little less copy/paste work at least.

```
var textBoxes = new List<TextBox> { Tol1, Tol2, Tol3, Tol4, Tol5, Tol6 };

for (var i = 0; i < lineTolFront.Count; i++)
    textBoxes[i].Text = lineTolFront[i].ToString();
```

Regarding M Patel's comment, make sure you add the TextBoxes to the collection in the same order you want to assign the doubles from the `lineTolFront` array.

Comment: Same as @DaveZuch above, if the collection was ordered as new[] { Tol3, Tol1, Tol2, Tol5, Tol4, }; this code would become invalid

Comment: Sure but that's not what the post above says. Tol3 needs value a index 3

Answer (score 0):

You could add your controls to an array and loop through it:

```
var controls = new[] { Tol1, Tol2, Tol3, Tol4, Tol5, }; //etc
for(int i = 0; i < controls.Length; i++)
{
    controls[i].Text = lineTolFront[i].ToString();
}
```

Comment: This is OK but if the collection was ordered as new[] { Tol3, Tol1, Tol2, Tol5, Tol4, }; this code would become invalid